# WM_CHAR messages in subclassed window

Tags: winapi

I'm attempting to implement an auto-complete feature in a Word add-in, and consequently need a way to detect when the user is typing in the document. As this isn't an event offered by the Office API, my strategy is to monitor WM_CHAR messages on the document window. To do this I've determined the handle of the actual window within Word that receives keyboard input, and tried subclassing it using `SetWindowSubclass`.

However when testing this, WM_CHAR messages aren't seen by my WndProc. WM_KEYDOWN/UP messages are, but not WM_CHAR. ***Is it true that a subclassed WndProc necessarily receives all messages that the original WndProc would have?*** I can see in Spy++ that the window I subclassed is having WM_CHAR messages posted to it.

I believe this could be done with Hooks, but I've heard they are quite hungry as far as performance goes, and subclassing the specific windows seems a lot cleaner in this instance.

Comment: WM_CHAR is generated by TranslateMessage(), maybe Word doesn’t call it.

Comment: of course that subclassed wndproc received exactly the same messages that original

Comment: @RbMm must we conclude therefore that, since WM_CHAR messages were posted to that window, DispatchMessage was never called on the WM_CHAR message as part of Word's message loop (perhaps instead invoking the original WndProc directly)? That would leave me no option but to monitor WM_CHAR messages via a WH_GETMESSAGE hook...

Comment: may be another subclassed procedure called before your and it not passed to the next subclass procedure. however this is very easy research under debugger - what is happens. set breakpoint on `WM_KEYDOWN` handler in your code. and debug next `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` and `DispatchMessage` - will be visible what exactly happens

Comment: Is this not perhaps related to a UNICODE / ANSI mismatch between the WindowProc and the subclass windowproc?

Comment: @ChrisBecke my WndProc is part of a Unicode DLL and `IsWindowUnicode` returns TRUE for the window of interest. Using neither `SetWindowLongPtrW` or `SetWindowLongPtrA` seem to pick up WM_CHAR messages though.